# Login button is not redirecting to login page in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, material-ui

I have a login button in home page. When I click on that it will redirect to login page in chrome and edge but not in firefox. I am not able to get how to resolve this. Please help me fixing this.

```
export default class Welcome extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let button
        if(this.props.status){
            button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.props.logout} />;
        }else{
            button = <LoginButton />;
        }

        return(
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <Typography variant="h5">
                    Welcome
                </Typography>  
                {button}
            </header>
        )
    }
}


function LoginButton() {
    console.log("test")
    return (
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" style={{margin: '2rem'}}>
            <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
        </Button>
    );
}

function LogoutButton(props) {
    return (
        <Button onClick={props.onClick}>
            Logout
        </Button>
    );
}
```

And in console it is showing the below warning in only firefox

"The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed"

Comment: Could you also post the versions of your package dependencies?

Comment: I haven't looked into the cause yet, but I have reproduced this using [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1q0npr5o13).

Comment: Though I did not see the console message you mentioned ("The Components object is deprecated...") and I don't think it is directly related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing behavior due to the browser differences, but the Firefox behavior is reasonable.

In the end, by having a `Link` inside a `Button` you are producing html like the following:

```
<button><a href="/login">Log In</a></button>
```

In Firefox, it appears that the `button` receives the click event and doesn't pass it through to the `a` element.

One way to fix this is to have the Material-UI `Button` use `Link` as the outer component:

```
<Button
  component={Link}
  to="/login"
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  style={{ margin: "2rem" }}
>
  Log In
</Button>
```

This also fixes some styling issues (text being underlined/blue) with your initial approach (though you may have overridden the default `a` styles in your app so that this wasn't noticeable).

Below is a CodeSandbox demonstrating three login button approaches:

- The solution approach with `component={Link} to="/login"` as props on `Button`
- A simple `<button><Link to="/login">Log In</Link></button>` version to show that this also doesn't work in Firefox
- Your original version

[image: Edit z6672vqm73]